# What happens if my current residence permit expires before my application for a new one is processed?

Tags: schengen, long-stay-visas, residence-permits

I am a non-EU citizen with a residence permit in France expiring some day soon.

I have started the application for a new residence permit (and I believe I have the right documents, if that's relevant).

However, the French authority (the Prefecture) has not processed my application for a residence permit yet. All I have for proof is a PDF saying that I submitted an application.

I have followed France's guideline of applying for a residence permit (i.e. at least two months before my current one expires). However, it has been two months since I made my application and they have not yet gotten back to me.

Can I stay in France / EU with an expired residence permit but with this PDF proof that I have an application waiting?

I have looked at the other possibly relevant topics but my question has not been answered as most of them ask about travelling. My question is about staying while waiting.

Comment: Searching (and asking) at [Expatriates Stack Exchange](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions) will bring you better results.

Comment: Read the letter they gave you very carefully. I am not sure about France's procedures, but in Austria (where I live on a residence permit) once you have given your application to the authority it extends the validity of your current permit until they make a decision.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I don't think any document I received told me that my current permit's validity extends automatically. I'm changing status from being a researcher to an employee, if that makes a difference.

Comment: @PepeSmith I am sure that it's the same in France as Austria. The best place to ask would be either the authority or your employer. I made the same switch here (from a 2yr researcher permit to a 3 yr skilled worker permit).

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that you have an [*attestation de dépôt de demande de renouvellement de carte de séjour*](https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F36206), i.e. an acknowledgement that you have made a request to renew your residence permit. Unfortunately, this document doesn't really help.

> Cette attestation n'est pas un document provisoire de séjour. Il ne justifie pas de la régularité de votre séjour.

“This attestation is not a temporary residence permit. It cannot be used as evidence that you are in the country legally.”

If they take more than **three months** (not two) to process your application, you should get either an “*attestation de prolongation de l'instruction de la demande*” (attestation that the response to the application has been lengthened) or ideally an “*attestation de décision favorable à la demande*” (attestation that the application has been approved). For a renewal, both allow you to stay in France and work.

If you can apply in person at the *(sous)-préfecture*, then someone will check that you've submitted all the required papers on the spot, and they will deliver a *[récépissé de demande de renouvellement de titre de séjour](https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F15763)*. Unlike an *attestation*, a *récépissé* does allow you to stay in France. It also allows you to work in most (all?) cases where the *carte de séjour* will allow you to work.

The list on the French government site correspond to the [list of documents allowing entry into the Schengen area](https://home-affairs.ec.europa.eu/list-residence-permits-issued-member-states_en). You can enter with an *attestation de prolongation de l'instruction* or a *récépissé* but not with an *attestation de dépôt de la demande*. (Some countries' temporary documents don't allow entering through another Schengen country — this is one of the few exceptions where you can't enter the Schengen area wherever you want — but France's temporary documents are recognized by the other Schengen countries.)

I have no idea if it's possible to apply in person in the post-Covid era. The procedures depend on the *préfecture*. Unfortunately, in many places, you need an appointment and it's effectively impossible to get one.